# Copyright issue while upload apps to itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I get this issue from apple after upload my apps for review.

> We found that your app includes features for streaming TV channels, the content of which may be copyrighted. The use of materials copyrighted by a third party requires documented evidence of your right to use such content in your application.
>
> Please provide the documentary evidence showing your rights to use this content, to ensure compliance with the iOS Developer Program License Agreement. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with your app review. Be aware that while your iTunes Connect Application State is displayed as Rejected, it is not necessary to upload a new binary if you only need to address issues in your metadata.
>
> Please remember that pursuant to your agreement with Apple, you represent and warrant that your application does not infringe the rights of another party, and that you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim that your application infringes another party's rights.

I wanna ask how to upload the documentary evidence showing the rights??
Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: We are programmers, not lawyers :-S.  This is off topic.

Comment: you can upload documents to your server and attach the link to the documents in the reply to the Apple.

Comment: I'm not talking how to make the copyright @borrrden.

Where I can reply and send the documents @sharon?

Comment: Oh, that is still off topic though.  This site is for programming problems.

Answer (score 4):

I know this **Question** is **Off topic** but i had the Same Issue that's why sharing this. When i submitted my **iOS App**. As you are providing streaming for some channels on you **iOS App** then you need to share the agreements documents to **Apple Review team**. For share the documents you can use the **itunesconnect** like when **Apple Review team** wrote the details reason of rejection In **Resolution Center** you can scan the documents and send from there or you can write a email to **Apple Review Team** on `appreview@apple.com` or Contact through the [Support Center](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/) and share all the details like your **App ID** , **Rejection issue** etc.

Once you share these Documents with **Apple Review Team** and after verification there is no need to submit another thing for App Update or something else.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Just wondering why you used inline code syntax for names?

Comment: @JoshuaDance I used for highlighting some words in my answer if there is any other way to this. Please edit and improve it. Thanks a lot teammate

Comment: @BuntyMadan please can you specify which document to provide to Apple to resolve this issue.. I am using live tv streaming url (in webview) which is hosted by some other company on my behalf..