# Use of webview to show live channel hosted on URL

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, webview, app-store

I have a live streaming URL for my client's TV channel which I need to use in their app. A third party company is hosting this service for the client company. I am using it through an `iframe` / `webview` in my app as follows :

```
    let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"" width=\"100%\" height=\"500\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe></body></html>" 
    //src link removed
    liveWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

It works completely fine but my app got rejected on the app store due to:

> Your app includes features for streaming TV channels, the content of which may be copyrighted. The use of third-party copyrighted materials requires documented evidence of your right to use such content in your app.

So I have few questions here: If I have a URL hosting live tv and want to use the same in my app, so is webview the only option? Is there any better option?
And, is the use of webview creating this app store issue?

Also I have seen many questions on this app store issue but no answers tells clearly which document is to be submitted to resolve this.

Someone please answer this..

Comment: Better option for what? Did you read what the apple rejection said? What difference does it make if you implement using a webview or superview? The rejection will remain the same. And this is a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832356/copyright-issue-while-upload-apps-to-itunes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1) If I have a URL hosting live tv and want to use the same in my app, so is webview the only option?*
**It's not, you can implement a native player using AVFoundation. If you're interested in a native solution I recommend looking at the AVFoundation framework documentation and this [example of a working player from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html)**

*2) Is there any better option?*
**A native solution is much more customizable but I wouldn't say it's worse or better, it really depends on what you need.**

*3) And, is the use of webview creating this app store issue?*
**No, it's the not related to you using a webview. You could have the same rejection with a native player.**

***To summarize:***

As said this doesn't look like a technical problem at all and you would probably encounter the same rejection if you implement a native player.

When you submit the app you need to provide copyright information, explaining that the owner of the app (your client) is the same owner of the content being streamed through the app.

Providing evidence of this should be enough to get the review passed.

> 5.2.1 Generally: Don’t use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrighted works, or patented ideas in your app without
>   permission, and don’t include misleading, false, or copycat
>   representations, names, or metadata in your app bundle.

from [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: PO is asking: "If I have a URL hosting live tv and want to use the same in my app, so is webview the only option? Is there any better option? And, is the use of webview creating this app store issue?" I think I have answered this 1) it's not the only option, 2) it's not necessarely better, doesn't matter regarding to the rejection 3) no, it's the the use of the webview the problem.

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same answer as what Apple said. "The use of third-party copyrighted materials requires documented evidence of your right to use such content in your app." Update your answer with links to the documentation or further information regarding it would make it an answer. However, there are a dozens of these questions made , flag it as duplicate or off-topic or use the comment section.

Comment: @tanzolone Thanks for the answer! Can you tell me which are the other options to use live tv URL in app?

Comment: @Dia Updated my answer. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Dia it's depend on your liveTv Url extension e.g ".m3u8 , "Rtsp" ,"Rtmp" ,"Ts" ,"Hls" the all are Live tv Url Extension Available. so wich one is yours?

Comment: @tanzolone Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Nilesh I just have the URL abc.com/livetv (I've replaced actual site with abc).. So how do i know what is the extension?

Comment: @Dia you just check url is play into my answer demo or not , if yes then implement in your project. prefer my answer link and test url.